# Akka Streams / HTTP: Get original request from response

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have an Akka Streams source that goes through a flow and posts an HTTP request:

```
source.map(toRequest)
  .via(Http().outgoingConnection(host))
  .map(toMessage)
```

Suppose that the `toRequest` method maps a string to an `HttpRequest`, and the `toMessage` method maps the `HttpResponse` to a message class that is needed to process downstream. Suppose that the message class needs to contain some of the original information.

Is it possible to get the original `HttpRequest` from the `HttpResponse`? If not, is there any way to keep some of the original information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use a [`Future`-based variant](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.1.1/client-side/request-level.html#future-based-variant) of the client API and a custom case class that holds the information you want to propagate downstream. For example:

```
case class Message(request: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse)

source
  .map(toRequest)
  .mapAsync(parallelism = 3) { request => // adjust the level of parallelism as needed
    Http().singleRequest(request).map(response => Message(request, response))
  }
  // continue processing; at this point you have a Source[Message, _]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use your graph api to by-pass your HttpRequest. One example would be:

```
object Main extends App {

  implicit val as = ActorSystem("Test")
  implicit val m = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val ec = as.dispatcher

  def src1 = Source.fromIterator(() => List(1, 2, 3).toIterator)

  val srcGraph = Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    // Create one flow to prepend the 'Number' string to the input integer
    def flow1 = Flow[Int].map { el => s"Number $el"  }

    // Create a broadcast stage 
    val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
    val zip       = builder.add(Zip[Int, String]())

    src1 ~> broadcast.in

    // The 0 port sends the int to the zip stage directly
    broadcast.out(0) ~>          zip.in0
    broadcast.out(1) ~> flow1 ~> zip.in1

    SourceShape(zip.out)
  })

  Source.fromGraph(srcGraph).runForeach(println(_))
}
```

The graph api provides many options to do things like this.