# How to associate an input element with an output element transparently

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I get a `Flow<A, B>` (which is a fancy stream/graph thingy, see https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.html) from some external code out of my control. I need to wrap that flow and do some processing on every input element and every output element. I can easily achieve this by putting a [`BidiFlow`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/BidiFlow.html) on top of it like this:

```
Flow<I, O, Unused> flow = ...; // external source
BidiFlow<I, I, O, O, Unused> bidi = BidiFlow.fromFunctions(i -> preprocess(i), o -> postprocess(o)); // do something on every input and every output
Flow<I, O, Unused> newFlow = bidi.join(flow);
```

So here is the twist: to correctly post-process the output element `o`, I need the input that generated that output element. Since I don't have control of the underlying flow, I cannot refactor it to return, for example, a tuple of the input and the output. And due to the asynchronous and parallel nature of Akka, I cannot do any tricks like storing the input on the thread local or a static field or something similar.

So my question: is there some Akka Streams magic I can apply to somehow get the input element that generated the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution of using GraphDsl, Broadcast and Zip stages.

```
  val externalFlow: Flow[Int, String, NotUsed] = Flow[Int].map(i => i.toString + "-external")

  def zipInAndOut[I, O](flow: Flow[I, O, NotUsed]): Flow[I, (I, O), NotUsed] = {
    Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._
      val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[I](2))
      val zip = b.add(Zip[I, O])
      val theFlow = b.add(flow)
      broadcast.out(0) ~> zip.in0
      broadcast.out(1) ~> theFlow ~> zip.in1
      new FlowShape(broadcast.in, zip.out)
    })
  }
  Source
    .fromIterator(() => (1 until 10).iterator)
    .via(zipInAndOut(externalFlow))
    .runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
```

prints

```
(1,1-external)
(2,2-external)
(3,3-external)
(4,4-external)
(5,5-external)
(6,6-external)
(7,7-external)
(8,8-external)
(9,9-external)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph Api. You can broadcast you input to two flows, one to make your process and another one to by-pass your ID. The las task should be a zip of these flows. Take a look to [Akka Streams / HTTP: Get original request from response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332669/akka-streams-http-get-original-request-from-response/50334504#50334504). Maybe it can help.

Comment: Nice idea. Im currently looking into it and i try to understand the code in the comment of your link. However, im not entirely sure, does this zipping correctly respect parallelism? My thinking is, as elements are broadcasted, how can the correct ones be associated with each other when i zip them again?

Comment: could u elaborate more how this would apply? I dont really understand your sample, the sample is working with sources (that are not really the same types as in my case and I dont know how to transform them into each other), and uses operators I dont find anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Elements broadcasted will be in order after your zip stage, unless you don´t do thinks like filtering or include async IO operations or parallelism in one of them that could alter the order. The example uses the Graph API https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-graphs.html

Comment: Did u read the question properly? U continue to link examples where vital parts are missing. As stated in my original question, i need to wrap an existing flow, i.e., i dont have a source and sink i can work with. Also, it may be asynchronous, that is what the original question is about. And i know understand your comment as "it doesnt work with asynchronous flows"